# Free member is not working

Tags: freemember

```
    `enter preformatted text here`    {exp:freemember:login return="shop/checkout" error_handling="inline" error_delimiters='<span class="error">|</span>'}

          <p>
              <label for="email">Email</label><br />
              {field:email}<br />
              {error:email}
          </p>

          <p>
              <label for="password">Password</label><br />
              {field:password}<br />
              {error:password}
          </p>

          <p>
              {field:auto_login} <label for="auto_login">Remember Me</label>
          </p>

          <p>
              <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
              <a href="{path='shop/checkout'}">Create Account</a>
          </p>

        {/exp:freemember:login}

    Trying with standared example code also not working for me.
    i have assign order field to member field in store configuration and other settings were right.
    But still not logging in.
   Updated : 02092015
    Here is the custom code that also always giving email error
    {exp:freemember:register return='shop/checkout' error_handling="inline" error_delimiters='<div class="error">|</div>'}
                <div class="mini_registration">
                    <div class="sus-username">
                      <input class="welurfield regsolofield"  type="text" name="username" value="{username}" placeholder="User Name" maxlength="32" size="25">
                            {error:username}
                    </div>
                    <div class="sus-customername">
                      <div class="sus-name"><input class="firstname" type="text" name="first_name" value="{first_name}" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="32" size="25"></div>
                      <div class="sus-name"><input class="lastname"  type="text" name="last_name" value="{last_name}" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="32" size="25"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <input type="text" name="username" value="{email}" placeholder="User Email" maxlength="50" size="25">
                        {error:email}
                    </div>
                    <div class="sus-password">
                      <input class="password_input"  type="text" name="password" value="{password}" placeholder="Your Password" maxlength="50" size="25">
                      {error:password}
                    </div>
                    <div class="sus-passconfirm">                   
                      <input class="passconfirm_input"  type="text" name="password_confirm" value="{password_confirm}" placeholder="Password Again" maxlength="32" size="25">
                      {error:password_confirm}
                    </div>
                    <div class="sus-regcaptcha">
                      {if captcha}
                        <div class="welcome_captcha"><span class="captchaline">Please enter the following characters into the box below:</span><br />
                          <div class="captchaline">{captcha}</div>
                          <div class="captchaline">{field:captcha}</div>
                          <div class="captchaline">{error:captcha}</div>
                        </div>
                      {/if}
                    </div>
                    <div class="sus-terms">
                      <div class="sus-termswrap">
                        <div class="sus-termstext"><input class="us-btn-orange" type="checkbox" name="accept_terms" value="1" {accept_terms} /><div class="termstext">Accept applicable www.susdus.com- T&C's</div></div>
                        {error:accept_terms}                            
                        <div class="sus-submit ">
                          <div class="submit_value"><input class="submit_input us-btn us-btn-smallbuy us-btn-orange" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 {/exp:freemember:register} This is the code i am using and always giving me email field required error
```

Comment: It is always best to remove `error_handling="inline" error_delimiters='<span class="error">|</span>'` from your templates if you are not seeing expected results to be shown the default EE error page.

Comment: Now its validating the required fields and redirecting it, but it not seems to be get logging in with sign in. This is for login side. For registration, it always saying email id is required error though i have given input in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an htaccess that adds a trailing slash at the end? That prevents 
freeform from working. You can disable it for POST requests with the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST` above the rule in .htaccess

More info https://github.com/devdemon/freemember/issues/81